# Dynamic pages at load time, not build time

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gatsby, sanity

I'm building an editorial site that regularly adds new content. As such, they've requested that articles and article content is loaded in at *load time* rather than having to run a build and wait for it. The speed is quite important for them and even after spending some time optimizing the build speed, they need it quicker.

I have the articles pulling in fine using the sanity client, but when you click on an article it's looking for `the-slug-of-the-article.js` rather than some kind of article page. If I could have it load something like `article.js` I could use the slug param from the URL to grab the page content, but I'm not sure how to actually load the page instead of `the-slug.js` without changing the URL structure.

To make things a bit more confusing, there's actually a category in here too, so the URL looks like: `www.example.com/category/the-slug-of-the-article`

Comment: This is how a traditional server application works. You’re probably better off looking at [Express](https://expressjs.com/), [Redwood](https://redwoodjs.com/), or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't build dynamic pages at "load" time using a static site generator.

### TL;DR

---

I assume that you are generating a final client site. Otherwise, you can achieve what you are trying to do using an EC2 instance of AWS (or similar in any other service) that runs a `gatsby develop`. Gatsby enables a feature to [refresh the content](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/refreshing-content/) automatically sending a `curl` request to its own domain with the `__refresh` URL parameter. For its own behavior, of course, it's only available in `gatsby develop`:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/__refresh
```

To do so, you will need to able `ENABLE_GATSBY_REFRESH_ENDPOINT` [environment variable](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/environment-variables/), so you will need to adapt your running commands.

Of course, `gatsby develop` won't refine and build the "final" static site, without all SEO, code improvements nor asset optimization as `gatsby build` does, so this approach may work only for testing purposes.

In your case, Sanity adds a watcher that makes this work easier for you. You will only need to enable the [`watchMode` flag](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-sanity/#options) like:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-sanity`,
  options: {
    projectId: `abc123`,
    dataset: `blog`,
    token: process.env.SANITY_TOKEN,
    graphqlTag: 'default',
    watchMode: true,
  },
},
```

*Note: by default is set to `false`.*

If it's not your case and you want to build a static site and show "live" content as soon as an article is published you will need to configure [webhooks](https://support.gatsbyjs.com/hc/en-us/articles/360052324394-Build-and-Preview-Webhooks) between your CMS (where the articles are written) and the server.

Basically, a webhook is an action that throws/notifies another action in the server. For example, as soon as an article is published in the CMS, the webhook will notify the server to run a deployment to publish the article. Of course, this action will take some time, depending on your project's size and the code optimization, from tens of seconds to up +15 minutes (in the worse cases).

The webhook implementation will depend and rely on the CMS and the server but more or less all of them are quite similar.

Keep in mind that you are serving static content that needs to be compiled, bundled, and built, that's why Gatsby is so fast (and all the static site generators indeed) so you can't bypass this process in a final client site to show "live" articles using this technology.